# Jekyll 2.0 Issues in Grunt/Yeoman

Tags: jekyll

I've been using Jekyll 2.0 directly from the command line for the last few days. I've put all my page files into a **'/pages'** folder so it looks like this:

```
/pages
  - index.html
  - about.html
  - contact.html
```

In the front matter of each page I set the permalink like this:

```
permalink: /about/
```

So when Jekyll compiles the site, I'm able to navigate successfully to **localhost:8888/about/** it's been working really well.

***The Grunt/Yeoman problem:***

I've picked up the [generator-jekyllrb](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/generator-jekyllrb) for Yeoman today because I want Grunt to manage everything (live reloading etc). I set it up, everything is working fine... but Jekyll is no longer generating the folders according to the permalink.

For example, my "**about.html**" page inside **/pages**, is not having an "**/about**" folder generated in the root like it did when using Jekyll directly. So I can only access the page through: **localhost:8888/pages/about/**. Which is strange.

Here's my [**Gruntfile.js**](http://cl.ly/code/1i0b2t1w1W2v) generated from Yeoman

I don't know a whole great deal about this stuff. I'm very new to Grunt and the CL, but this has really stumped me. If anyone could offer any advice or point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following to my **_config.yml**:

```
relative_permalinks: false
```

which fixed the problem. I think grunt-jekyllrb must be a version behind or something, because absolute permalinks are defaults now in the latest Jekyll.